# An algorithm to split concatenated names

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

My problem is

I have full names with concatenated names, like "**davidrobert jones**". I want to split it to be "**david robert jones**".

I tested the solutions using longest prefix matching algorithm with a names dictionary, but it's not that simple because a name could be written in many ways.
I added phonetic matching algorithm too, but also there are many names that could have same pronunciation and so they're very ambiguous.

What is the best solution to do so?, i believe machine learning could have an answer, but i don't know much about machine learning.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but I suppose the names do not generally have an uppercase letter at the split point, right? In any case, as it is stated, the question is too broad and not very well defined; for example, "Jeanmarie", "Jean-Marie" and "Jean Marie" are all plausible names.

Comment: Well, i see it a challenging question. i edited the question to clear the question more, the full name is all lowercase letters. And if a name is plausible name doesn't mean it's the right name of the person.

Comment: Your question is also rather ill-defined. You say you want to capture different spellings for the same name, but then you don't want names that sound the same with a different spelling. Then you want to guess the "right name", but there's no way to tell if "Jeanmarie" or "Jean Marie" is the right answer. A data-driven approach (eg. using machine-learning) might help you get the most plausible one (not necessarily the right one), but you seem not to want that...

Comment: Can you provide more examples, including the ones causing most problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is similar to [Named Entity Recognizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). **Named Entity Recognition (NER)** labels sequences of words in a text which are the names of things, such as person and company names. In section 5 this [article](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#sec-ner) has python method for `Named Entity Recognition`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible algorithmic solution is to create a longer compositional dictionary representing all possible **first_name last_name**. Then for any given list of tokens as a name (words separated with space), for each token, find all dictionary enteries which have shortest edit distance to that token